# get current Page Layout in SharePoint 2010 using ECMA script

Tags: 2010, javascript

I have a requirement that I need to create a custom page layout and need to update the current page layout with my custom page layout. In SharePoint we have a feature to change the page layout.

But I have to change that page layout using my custom control in SharePoint ribbon. So I need to access current page_layout and current page_layout controls.

Any one please help me on this?

Comment: I don't understand why the OOTB ribbon button to set the layout for the current page doesn't meet your needs?

Comment: yes, Ineed to add new features to the ribbon custom control

Comment: Good luck with that, try this for help: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2011/10/my-ribbon-samples-from-spc11-session.html